# Unable to solve system of equations in Lagrange multiplier problem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

The problem: Find the right triangular prism of given volume and least area if the base is required to be a right triangle.

As for parameters of the right triangular prism, $V$ is volume, $A$ is surface area, $a$ and $b$ are legs of right triangle, and $h$ is the height.

Function to be minimized is then $A=ab+ah+bh+\sqrt {a^2+b^2}h$, and the constraint is $V=\frac 12abh$, where $V=constant$.

Then form the function $F=ab+ah+bh+\sqrt {a^2+b^2}h+\lambda\frac 12abh$, and calculate its gradient with each partial set to zero.

$$
(1)\frac {\partial F} {\partial a}=b+h+\frac {ah} {\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}+\lambda\frac 12bh=0,
$$
$$
(2)\frac {\partial F} {\partial b}=a+h+\frac {bh} {\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}+\lambda\frac 12ah=0,
$$
$$
(3)\frac {\partial F} {\partial a}=a+b+\sqrt {a^2+b^2}+\lambda\frac 12ab=0,
$$

Then with the gradient of $F$ set equal to zero and the constraint, $V=\frac 12abh$, there are four equations with four unknowns($a, b, h, \lambda$).

My attempts to solve the set of four equations result in forbidding amounts of algebra. My most promising attempt involved multiplying (1) by $a$, (2) by $b$, and (3) by $h$, then adding those three equations together and solving for $\lambda$. But it was not successful.

This is my first time posting here and I hope I didn't make any mistakes with the syntax. Any help would be much appreciated so that I can continue with my self-studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first do what you started but (1)*a +(2)*b -(3)*h. Then 
The first new equation will be
$$
2ab+1/2\lambda abh=0
$$
Assuming that $V>0$ we can get $a,b,h>0$. Thus we immediately obtain 
$$
h=-4/\lambda;
$$

Now let's
(1)*a-(2)*b and divide by $h$.
$$
(a-b)+\frac{(a^2-b^2)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=0
$$
The last equaiton implies that or $a=b$  otherwise $a+b<0$. So from (3) we have:

EDITED
$$
a(2+\sqrt{2}-2/ha)=0
$$
This implies that $h/a=\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and $V=\frac{a^3}{2+\sqrt{2}}$
I hope I did not make a mistake here. From here we obtam $a=b$ and $h$.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you very much!